# In vue3's tsx writeup, when a reactive variable is modified, does the entire return get refreshed, or does the call occur locally?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tsx

Why in my example, genComponent2 is triggered when the variable in genComponent is changed ?

```
<script lang="tsx">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

function genComponent() {
    console.log(`genComponent`)
  const a = ref('kkk');
  setTimeout(() => {
    a.value = 'aaa';
    console.log(`change to aaaa!!!`);
  }, 3000);
  return <div>{a.value}</div>;
}

function genComponent2() {
    console.log(`genComponent2`)
  const a = ref('zzz');
  return <div>{a.value}</div>;
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  setup() {
    return () => 
    <div>
        <div>
        {
            genComponent()
        }
        </div>
        <div>
        {
            genComponent2()
        }
        </div>
    </div>
  },
});
</script>
```

I wanna know the update timing in vue3 so that I can debug my code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `genComponent2` is called on every render in render function, and the component is re-rendered when reactive value is changed inside `getComponent`. `setTimeout` is called on every `genComponent` call, so it can be called many times instead of one.

Refs are supposed to be defined in the body of setup, it's generally a mistake to make them local to other functions. There's no benefit from defining `getComponent`, etc outside component, it could be rewritten as:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  setup() {
    const a = ref('kkk');
    const a2 = ref('zzz');

    // Needs a cleanup
    setTimeout(() => {
      a2.value = 'aaa';
    }, 3000);

    function genComponent() {
      return <div>{a.value}</div>;
    }
    
    function genComponent2() {
      return <div>{a2.value}</div>;
    }

    return () =>
    ...
```